# How can I have increasing named variables?

Tags: variables, python-3.x, named

I want a bunch of buttons, using QtGui to all have their own unique values, but when looping to create a grid of them, the button variable is overwritten.

I was trying to get something that would have each button have its own variable, like grid_btn01, grid_btn02, and so on.

Ideally, it would be like this

```
for x in range(gridx):
     grid_btn + str(x) = GridBtn(self, x, y, btn_id)
```

But of course, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using a python dictionary

,also i'm not familiar with Qt but double check what is the return value of this function maybe `btn_id` is the variable you should store

```
buttons = {}
for x in range(gridx):
    buttons[x] = GridBtn(self,x,y,btn_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking may technicallybe possible in Python, but it's definitely the wrong approach.

Use a list instead:

```
grid_btns = []
for x in range(gridx):
    y = ...
    grid_btns.append(GridBtn(self, x, y, btn_id))
```